# Returning multiple streams from LINQ query

Tags: c#, linq

I want to write a LINQ query which returns two streams of objects. In F# I would write a Seq expression which creates an IEnumerable of 2-tuples and then run Seq.unzip. What is the proper mechanism to do this in C# (on .NET 3.5)?

Cheers, Jurgen

Comment: Hackish solution:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15690478

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your best bet is probably to create a `Pair<T1, T2>` type and return a sequence of that. (Or use an anonymous type to do the same thing.)

You can then "unzip" it with:

```
var firstElements = pairs.Select(pair => pair.First);
var secondElements = pairs.Select(pair => pair.Second);
```

It's probably worth materializing `pairs` first though (e.g. call `ToList()` at the end of your first query) to avoid evaluating the query twice.

Basically this is exactly the same as your F# approach, but with no built-in support.

Comment: If your enumerable is expensive to calculate or infinite then you will need a more complex solution to avoid doubly materialising the input than ToList. An implementation of partition using Queues to cache the results from the output not being iterated would do it.

Answer (score 2):

Due to the lack of tuples in C# you may create an anonymous type.
Semantics for this are:

```
someEnumerable.Select( inst => new { AnonTypeFirstStream = inst.FieldA, AnonTypeSecondStream = inst.FieldB });
```

This way you're not bound in the amount of streams you return, you can just add a field to the anonymous type pretty like you can add an element to a tuple.

Comment: System.Tuple is available in C#.

Comment: @NathanPhillips, System.Tuple was introduced with .NET 4.0, which was released almost a year after this answer was written.